# Issue with geolocation in IE11

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, geolocation

I have the following code that requests the user to allow their current location in the browser, when they click/tap on the location-link.

This works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but I can't get it to work in IE11. Some times it shows the browser notification for the user to give their location but then nothing happens.

I wondered if anyone else has had issues with Google Maps and requesting location in IE11 and also if anyone has a solution?

```
<p id="error"></p>
<form action="/" method="post">
<a class="location-link" id="location-link" href="#"><img src="/static/images/icons/location.png" alt="Get your current location" title="Get your current location" /></a><input type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Find a salon" >
<input class="viewbtn3" value="Submit" type="submit"></form>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
        $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
        $(".location-instruction span").hide();
        $(".location-link").hide();
        return;
    }
    $("#location-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));
        var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
        //console.log(thisid);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    $("#" + thisid).parent().find('input[name="location"]').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $(".choose_wrap").addClass('sucess');
                } else {
                    $("#" + thisid).parent().find("#error").html("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
                    $(".choose_wrap").addClass('fail');
                }
            })
        }, function(positionError) {
            $("#" + thisid).parent().find("#error").html("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />")
        }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it worked as same as in other browsers. Haven't got any problem

Comment: Hmm, did you try IE11 and Windows 10 by any chance?

Comment: Yes i had tried IE11 but it only had a margin setting probems.. nothing wrong with geolocation

Answer (score 5):

This actually worked for me on IE11 with no changes when I tried it out on Codepen:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
        $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
        $(".location-instruction span").hide();
        $(".location-link").hide();
        return;
    }
    $("#location-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));
        var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
        //console.log(thisid);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    $("#" + thisid).parent().find('input[name="location"]').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $(".choose_wrap").addClass('sucess');
                } else {
                    $("#" + thisid).parent().find("#error").html("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
                    $(".choose_wrap").addClass('fail');
                }
            })
        }, function(positionError) {
            $("#" + thisid).parent().find("#error").html("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />")
        }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<p id="error"></p>
<form action="/" method="post">
  <a class="location-link" id="location-link" href="#"><img src="/static/images/icons/location.png" alt="Get your current location" title="Get your current location" /></a>
  <input type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Find a salon">
  <input class="viewbtn3" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXZxgz

Only thing I can suggest is to check the developer console to see if there are any errors when you test it.

Comment: Thanks so much for checking Eric. Our client had a few people test and it didn't seem to work for them but I'll recheck that link with browserstack.

Comment: did you happen to use Windows 10? In Win10 and IE11, the browser asks for permission but then does nothing.

Comment: No, I'm on Windows 8.1 currently.  In Windows 10, I'd test Edge rather than IE11.  Maybe after you give permission, try reloading and doing it again.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this out on Windows 8.  If the location settings on the machine (see Control Panel/Change Location Settings) are turned off, an error message is  returned.  In the above code "nothing happens".  "#error" and "#location-link" don't share the same parent, so this line does not display the error message:

```
$("#" + thisid).parent().find("#error").html("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />")
```

Is this issue preventing the "Geo-location not turned on" message from showing up on client machines?

Comment: Hey brenzy, certainly an issue there if the error message doesn't display so i'll need to fix that up. Just don't understand why some users on IE11/Win10 can use the location search and some can't. But i'll try fix that error first.

Comment: @doubleplusgood, the reason might be either that they have the location settings turned off, and they don't know it, or that Microsoft doesn't support their location (see other so answers about why locations differ).  Hopefully fixing the error message will give you an answer as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a Windows setting, at least it was in my case. Try going to Settings (search from the Start menu in Windows) > Privacy > Location and turn Location = On.